# RealBoy emulator a real dud

Tags: arm, compatibility

There is an open source game boy emulator called realboy that I was hoping to use on pi, and modify slightly. I can get it to build on Ubuntu just fine. When I build it in raspbian, it does build (standard `./configure`; `make`; `sudo make install`) without problems, but then does not function correctly. It sometimes opens,  but does not show anything in the window. Sometimes it just has segmentation faults, or other problems completely crashing it.

Why would it work in Ubuntu and not Raspbian, given that I am theoretically using the exact same procedure? I was wondering if perhaps the make instructions need to be upgraded to cover special Raspbian ARM stuff?

Also, there is a dependency on SDL, so I installed that first in both cases.

I am also surprised that it builds but doesn't run correctly. I expected that if it built, it would work. If it didn't work, I would have expected the building step to fail.

Has anyone experienced similar issues? Perhaps with RealBoy? Or perhaps just building projects that may not have been tested on rpi?

***Update 1***

I suspect I may have found the answer. I re read the README, and it looks like I should be able to run `./configure --disable-asm` to use C code instead of assembly. I will try it this weekend and report back. Thanks to *tlhIngan* for his input thus far.

***Update 2***

`--disable-asm` did allow the make and install to execute completely, but the resulting program does not function (if I remember correctly, fatal memory exceptions were one porblem), and a game will never make it even as far as the start menu. Not sure what else to try. Perhaps I should try one more time on a fresh Raspberry Pi? Perhaps automake needs an additional setting to support ARM? I don't really know much about the configure make install process.

Comment: Maybe you can try https://retropie.org.uk/ ? It contains many emulators and maybe you can get Game Boy emulator https://github.com/retropie/retropie-setup/wiki/Game-Boy and just compile for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the repo](https://sourceforge.net/projects/realboy/), RealBoy contains some assembly code. Assembly code is:

1. Architecture-specific (x86 and x64 in RealBoy's case)
2. Not compiled, simpy "linked" with the compiled output of the rest of the code

That being said, the repo also mentions that the assembly section was completely rewritten in C, however this is not reflected in the changelog. I would contact the author and ask where this is or which version has all C code.